# Build contains beta entitlement - still get error

Tags: ios, jenkins, testflight

The embedded profile in my IPA's payload contains the beta-reports-active key with a following true value.  When those builds are uploaded, and later listed within itunesconnect pre-release tab they are flagged as NOT having that entitlement.  I am inspecting the embedded.profile with this command

`security cms -D -i`

In the p-list that is returned I see the `Entitlements` dict and within that `<key>beta-reports-active</key>` followed by `<true/>`.

Has anyone encountered this?  Could there be some other source of entitlements?

EDIT:

I should add the profile is being embedded by jenkins via it's XCODE plugin.

Comment: Have so far narrowed it down to the entitlments not getting recreated when resining - not sure why it's resining, but that seems the case!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it: 
Problem was that `xcodebuild` run by Jenkins could not find my correct mobileprovision during build, only during resining. Moving the certificate into `~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles` solved it.

Look for this line

```
Provisioning Profile: "XYZ"
```

in the build output, that's what being used to build (not to resign for the packaged IPA) and it has to be the right file.

I will probably switch to a more modern tool like fastlane to avoid stuff like this from now on...